# How to patch a directory?

Tags: cygwin, kohana, patch, kohana-3

I want to patch kohana with a file called request.patch, which I have in the root directory of my Kohana install. I am using cygwin in windows 7. The patch reads as follows:

```
820a821,823
>           // Convert dashes to underscores
>           $controller = strtr($this->controller, '-', '');
>           
822c825
<           $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$this->controller);
---
>           $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$controller);
831a835,837
>           
>           // Convert action dashes to underscores
>           $action = strtr($action, '-', '');
```

However when I cd to the kohana root and then try and apply this patch:

```
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/patch.exe -p0 < request.patch
```

I receive the following error:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 1
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
File to patch:
```

I mean I'd even just do this manually if I knew what files the numbers were refering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not sure that's a proper patch file. It doesn't have the filenames or anything (hence the error). Might better to grab the patch from github. You can append .patch on the end of a commit to get a proper patch file.

The numbers would be the line numbers in the file.

Comment: This is a valid diff file, but your comment got me to realise that yes, there aren't any files referenced - the numbers are just refering to lines of code in a file (with the a and c meaning added and changed respectively http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff). The patch name 'request.patch' refers to a file in system/classes/kohana called request.php - therefore I moved the patch file to that directory and ran `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/patch.exe request.php < request.patch` in cygwin. Thanks

Comment: Now that I look at it again,  it does look like a diff.